# Invoke Escape key press event by jQuery

Tags: jquery, keypress

Please don't confuse my question with determining the key press. I don't want the user to press any key. On the contrary, I want to run a script which fires the Escape key press event.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use `$.Event()` to create an Event object containing a keydown event with the keyCode of 27 (which should be Esc) like:

```
var esc = $.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 27 });
$("body").trigger(esc); // change body to the element where you'd like to execute the escape key press.
```

See **[this working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wbkm8/3/)** and the **[docs at jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)**

Also note that, as stated by Christofer, this might not be working in all browsers and environments as it might be considered *shady* behavior that *could* be used in a malicious manner - just like triggering a click event on an `<a>` with an external href **[will not happen](http://jsfiddle.net/hww92/)**. I successfully tested this (the Esc) in Chrome, Safari, Opera, FF & IE9 though.

Comment: @m90, How can we do the same thing in Angular?

Comment: @m90 How can we do the same thing in core Javascript not jQuery?

Answer (score 8):

For security reasons, some browsers (not sure if all), prevent you from firing keydown-events. Please refer to [this article](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domevents) for more info.

A quote from the article:

> Safari/Chrome makes the keyCode and charCode properties read-only, so
>   it is not possible to simulate specific keys when manually firing
>   events.