# How to simulate a keypress or Keyup when a link is clicked with jQuery

Tags: jquery, triggers, keypress, keyup, simulate

I am working with DataTable and TableTools plugins with jQuery.

I am trying to simulate a keyPress (or keyUp), when someone clicks a link in the page.

html code :

```
<a href='#' id='return'>رجوع</a>
```

jQuery code :

```
$('#return').click(function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).trigger(// code here // );
});
```

I can't find the code to put there.

Comment: not at all (or maybe I can't get it !). please the comments in the answer given by Anton. You'll understand my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$(this).trigger('keyup');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/vbByY/)

**Update**

Try this :

```
$('#return').click(function(evt) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var evt = jQuery.Event('keyup');
    evt.keyCode = 27;
    evt.which = 27;
    $(this).trigger(evt);
    alert(evt.keyCode);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/vbByY/2/)

Comment: Thanks. But what i'am looking for is to trigger a specefic keyup for example :ESC, or enter. The code for ESC is 27, but how to put it in the trigger function??

Comment: Thanks for the update, but it is still triggered with any key. I want it with just the ESC key. I think your solution would (should !) work, although i can't figure out why it's not.

Comment: Thanx @Anton for your help. What I was looking for is exactly what's in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070464/invoke-escape-key-press-event-by-jquery).