# How to create a link to trigger the escape key to close the full screen using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'd like to create a link to exit the full screen the same as when I click on the Escape key using jQuery. How can I trigger the escape key to exit the full screen?

Comment: Welcome to stackflow, could you show your code what you have tried til l now, then may be someone will be able to help you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invoke Escape key press event by jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070464/invoke-escape-key-press-event-by-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

In Gecko (Firefox) you can use the following code

```
window.document.mozCancelFullScreen();
```

In webkit (Chrome and more) you can try

```
window.document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
```

In Trident (Internet Explorer) will hopefully with prayers and some luck support this:

```
window.document.msCancelFullScreen();
```

For more read this article on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode